# Sending username string and password string to php when pressing the button

Tags: android

There are many post about my question in the internet. But they are a bit complicated. Please see the following code.

I want to send the `username` string and `password` string to a `php file` to use pressing the button.I know there are many post in the internet about it but when I see the posts I am confused.Which method I should use only to do so and I do not want additional methods and unnecessary.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
    String username =  user.getText().toString();
     String password = pass.getText().toString();
    //What I add?
    }}
```

Comment: If you found some example in _Google_ then used it. There are lots of ways to send data from device to server.

Comment: Find the least complicated, give it a shot, then post a more specific problem when you are stuck. There are too many possible answers for this to be a good fit for SO.

Comment: Note, you have a syntax error at the end of your `listener`. You need `});`, not just a closing brace.

Comment: @Scott Really you have a `Egale Eye`

Comment: @MD I've had plenty practice :p

Comment: Does the username and password are being writen (originally) on html form/page?

Comment: the app can communicate with the server through REST API, and there are android libraries that help you with that, like RETROFIT. Read about it and you will have a direction.